# How to do Multithreading in ios3.2 some issues arises

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have question that i am using ios 3.2 for iPad .. Its working on the iphone 4.1 but its not working on iPad ios 3.2

here is my code:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self myPrivateFunction];
        });
    });
```

Please tell me what can i do it for that..

Answer (score 1):

Well if you had taken the time to look into the docs, you would have seen that Grand Central Dispatch has been introduced to iOS with Version 4.0. So there is no way they will work on iOS Version 3.2.

Alternatives:
Use some of the async methods like `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` or roll out your own threading methods with [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

Answer (score 0):

GCD and blocks aren't available in iOS 3.2. For simple multi-threading, you can use `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` and `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Grand central dispatch is not available before iOS 4.0.
You can use NSInvocationOperation for async operation.